# Some older mainstream music no longer available on Vinyl "as new"? Only "second hand" market?

Tags: vinyl, metal

I am very new to the world of vinyl. I I really like [Das Modell](https://rammwiki.net/wiki/Das_Modell_(single)) and [Stripped](https://rammwiki.net/wiki/Stripped_(song)) by Rammstein.

I could not find any vinyl records of these two songs. When I do a web search, I always come up with used items.

Is it normal in the world of records that older but very popular songs are no longer in the new goods trade.

Is it normal to buy most records second hand, unfortunately mostly an auction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Historically, records were the dominant form of music reproduction for most of the 1900s. They were superseded by CDs in the 1990s, and became a niche (mainly radio and party DJs) product. Later, in the 2000s, they made a comeback as a boutique product (collectors, audiophiles, hipsters, people who like vintage things).

Music that first came out in the 1990s or early 2000s, like the Rammstein track, was likely initially released on CD only. So there was never a vinyl version (or very limited quantities of it). Some bands are reissuing music now on vinyl, even if it was never on vinyl before, but someone has to make a concerted effort to make that happen. Unless there a group of fans demanding it, it's unlikely to exist.

Records are expensive to create and bulky to store, especially in comparison to mp3s or streaming audio. So, while they can be much more profitable to musicians, per unit, to sell, it doesn't make sense to issue them without a solid market. It's also prohibitively expensive to do small runs--there's really no cost-effective "print on demand" for vinyl the way there is for books.

Comment: Might not mean so much to you if you're not British, but times seem so good for vinyl right now that HMV are reopening their flagship store - https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-england-london-65417131

Comment: @Tetsujin Vinyl is back in a big way on these shores as well. The only downside is that you can't get great finds for a quarter anymore, the way you could when everyone was selling off their collections.

Comment: My turntable has been sitting on a shelf in the back of my workroom for at least 20 years. I don't think I'm going to be digging it out any time soon. I like my music free of fuzzy snap, crackle & pop ;)

Comment: @Tetsujin - LOL, not me. I've always kept a turntable, even during the CD years, and I play vinyl probably 2-3 times a week. Def my favorite format, fuzz notwithstanding. Just the other day, one of my parent's friends gave me a box of old gems, including an unopened Nina Simone, still in the original plastic.

Comment: In a major living room re-jig, I ran out of space for what was an entire 2nd hifi - with turntable. I ended up just re-buying all my vinyl on CD, [sometimes more than once until they released one that didn't sound like it was made by the intern off the EQ master] …which of course was their *Evil Plan™* in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of vinyl is only made in limited quantities, once it's gone it's gone.

This always used to happen back in the days of vinyl's height, just the quantities were greater, so stock could hang around longer - unless it was shipped back for recycling, which tended to happen if your release wasn't as successful as anticipated.

Because of the recent resurgence, those initial pressing numbers may be growing again - but the industry is still wary of this just being a fad.